# How to get rid of blur logo in this Button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

This is my image:

[image]

I'm using 128 x 128 pixel png file image as my logo in button but it is still looking bad.

This is my code:

```
let createButton = UIButton(type: .system)
createButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "navigation.png").withRenderingMode(.automatic), for: .normal)
createButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
createButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
createButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
createButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: createButton)
```

Comment: Consider using a image scaled appropriately for the device (x1, x2, x3), which can be provided through assets catalog. I'd also consider using something like [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com) - because who wants to go through all the hassle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 1x, 2x, 3x image depends upon button size.
Consider button size is 50*50 then you need to use images 50*50, 100*100, 150*150 for 1x, 2x, 3x respectively.